# Need help with Classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i am new in ActionScript 3/ Flash CS4, i am learning classes in ActionScript(OOP). I have in my folder two files - Pro.fla (my flash project) and .as (Pro.as). I created class in Pro.as:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Pro extends MovieClip
    {
        private var  button:my_button=new my_button(); // is the button from the library (MovieClip), which has been linkage Base class: Pro and class: my_button

        public function Pro()
        {

            button.x+=2050;
                    }
    }
}
```

when i ctrl+enter, i have a mistake: Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow,
What is the problem, can anyone help me with that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a recursion issue. In your comment, you mentioned that "my_button" has a base class of "Pro". I'm guessing "Pro.as" is your Document class and not the base class of your button. Right now, because Pro is the base class of the button, and you're creating the button within Pro, it's creating an endless loop.

If you haven't created a base class for the button, you probably want to set it to "flash.display.Sprite" or "flash.display.MovieClip" to have it extend either Sprite or MovieClip.

Comment: or SimpleButton as @Daniel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The base class of the button should be `flash.display.SimpleButton` (or MovieClip)